# C - Detectar en que renglón/linea está un char

Tags: c

Para darles una idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo se que "a" está en tal linea y tal columna, al igual que b. Pero como puedo hacer que el programa me devuelva los valores de columna y linea? Algo así:

```
printf("&c",a);
printf("&c está en la linea %i y en la columna %i"
a,valor de linea,valor de columna);
```

Comment: No es un problema, simplemente no sé como hacer que el programa devuelva esos valores. No sé si es un ejemplo como tu dices pero creo que está claro lo que quiero que haga el programa.

Comment: Estas utilizando alguna clase de estructura? matrices por ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Quieres imprimir un texto y luego averiguar en que linea,columna de la pantalla quedó?

Answer (score -1):

Hey no lo explicaste pero supondré que buscas dentro de un archivo
Lo que tienes que hacer es buscar cada una de las letras en todo el archivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *archivo = fopen("dummy.txt", "r");
    char *letras_a_buscar = "ae";
    char linea[128];

    char letra;

    int len = strlen(letras_a_buscar);

    int numero_de_linea_actual = 0;

    // Por cada letra a buscar...
    for (int pos = 0; pos <= len; pos++)
    {
        letra = letras_a_buscar[pos];

        // buscar en cada linea en el archivo....
        while (fgets(linea, 128, archivo) != NULL)
        {
            numero_de_linea_actual += 1;
            // buscar en cada posición
            for (int n = 0; n != strlen(linea) - 1; n++)
            {
                if (letra == linea[n])
                {
                    printf("%c Linea %d, Columna %d\n", letra,
                           numero_de_linea_actual, n);
                }
            }
        }
        //reseteamos el archivo
        fseek(archivo,0, SEEK_SET);
    }

    fclose(archivo);
}
```

También podrías comparar cada letra del archivo con todas las letras ab buscar pero da igual. Espero haberte ayudado.

El archivo "dummy.txt" contiene

```
cccccccccccccaccccccc
cccccccbcccbccccccacc
ccccccccccccccceccccc
```